# How to set member elements focusable in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, focusable

I have a custom listview that has 3 editTexts inside it along with a button.

By defualt, I don't want the editTexts to be editable so I set

```
android:focusable="true"
```

But then at some point I want that button when clicked should make them editable

So inside getView(I am using a custom adapter) I set an onClick listener as:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Log.d("Reached: ","Getview");





        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.product_nameET= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_nameET);
            viewHolder.priceET= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceET);
            viewHolder.quantity_availableET= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_availableET);
            viewHolder.edit_button= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_rowButton);
            //viewHolder.product_nameET.setFocusable(true);
             final ViewHolder vh=viewHolder;
            viewHolder.edit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //lv.getChildAt(position).setFocusable(true);
                    vh.product_nameET.setFocusable(true);//////This line here has no effect


                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.product_nameET, viewHolder.product_nameET);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.priceET, viewHolder.priceET);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.quantity_availableET, viewHolder.quantity_availableET);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.edit_rowButton, viewHolder.edit_button);


        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        viewHolder.product_nameET.setText(product_namesList.get(position));
        viewHolder.priceET.setText(priceList.get(position));
        viewHolder.quantity_availableET.setText(quantity_availableList.get(position));






        return convertView;



    }
```

But this has no effect whatsoever. Please help I am new to android.

Comment: Have you try to use setFocusable and setFocusableInTouchMode both together ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana That worked

Comment: Great i have post answer please check and accept and upvote if it's resolve your problem so it will help other on same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set below two properties with true(enable)/false(disable) value based on conditions :

**For Enable EditText For Input:**

```
vh.product_nameET.setFocusable(true);
vh.product_nameET.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

**For Disable EditText For Input:**

```
vh.product_nameET.setFocusable(false);
vh.product_nameET.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the `KeyListener` value of `EditText` by `editText.getKeyListener()` and store in the `KeyListener` type variable, which will contain the editable property value:

```
KeyListener variable;
variable = editText.getKeyListener();
```

Set the editable property of `EditText` to `false` as:

```
edittext.setKeyListener(null);
```

Now set editable property of `EditText` to `true` as:

```
editText.setKeyListener(variable);
```

Note: In XML the default editable property of `EditText` should be `true`.

Comment: This is giving me a null pointer exception as when there are no items within the listview, the view is null.

Comment: yes its obvious without edittext it cant get refrence

Comment: you have to check null exception for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this one you need to enable the button.

```
   viewHolder.edit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //lv.getChildAt(position).setFocusable(true);
            viewHolder.product_nameET.setEnabled(true);

        }
    });
```